# How to update something like graph in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I have something like graph and i have a trouble.
I need to draw snowman, which moves on cosine trajectory.

```
import sys
import math
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
class MyFrame(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(800,600)
        scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(scene)

        for x in range(100):

            y = 100*(math.cos(x+200))

            pen1   = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red))
            brush1 = QtGui.QBrush(pen1.color().darker(255))
            item1 = scene.addEllipse(x, y, 100, 100, pen1,brush1)

            pen2   = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.green))
            brush2 = QtGui.QBrush(pen2.color().darker(150))
            item2 = scene.addEllipse(x-25, y+100, 150, 150, pen2,brush2)

            pen3   = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.blue))
            brush3 = QtGui.QBrush(pen3.color().darker(150))
            item3 = scene.addEllipse(x-50, y+250, 200, 200, pen3,brush3)
            time.sleep(3)



app = QtGui.QApplication([])
f = MyFrame()
f.show()
app.exec_()
```

Now i have some questions.
When i use `time.sleep(2)`, it's just wait for a few seconds and show me final result without steps. 
1) What i need to do for fixing it?
2) What i need to do for situation, when it looks like moving animation?
I tried to use QPoint, but it is a few hard to use in my code, i have no experience and i believe, that this problem solves more easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, you are doing your animation in the `__init__` method which means that the entire thing will complete before you've even shown the frame.  Instead break this into a separate method you call after `f.show()`.

**Second**, you need to throw a `processEvents()` call in during your animation to force `qt` to redraw the screen.

**Third**, you probably want to clear the scene in between drawings.

```
import sys
import math
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
class MyFrame(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(800,600)
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)

    def doAnimation(self):
        for x in range(5):

            self.scene.clear();
            y = 100*(math.cos(x+200))

            pen1   = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red))
            brush1 = QtGui.QBrush(pen1.color().darker(255))
            item1 = self.scene.addEllipse(x, y, 100, 100, pen1,brush1)

            pen2   = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.green))
            brush2 = QtGui.QBrush(pen2.color().darker(150))
            item2 = self.scene.addEllipse(x-25, y+100, 150, 150, pen2,brush2)

            pen3   = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.blue))
            brush3 = QtGui.QBrush(pen3.color().darker(150))
            item3 = self.scene.addEllipse(x-50, y+250, 200, 200, pen3,brush3)

            QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
            time.sleep(1)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
f = MyFrame()
f.show()
f.doAnimation()
app.exec_()
```